# Selecting only distinct rows based on a column in Knex

Tags: sql, knex.js

I'm using [Knex](http://knexjs.org/), a pretty nice SQL builder.

I've got a table called `Foo` which has 3 columns

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| id           | PK              |
+--------------+-----------------+
| idFoo        | FK (not unique) |
+--------------+-----------------+
| serialNumber | Number          |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

I'd like to select all rows with `idFoo IN (1, 2, 3)`.

However I'd like to avoid duplicate records based on the same `idFoo`.

Since that column is not unique there could be many rows with the same `idFoo`.

#### A possible solution

My query above will of course return all with `idFoo IN (1, 2, 3)`, even duplicates.

```
db.select(
  "id",
  "idFoo",
  "age"
)
.from("foo")
.whereIn("idFoo", [1, 2, 3])
```

However this will return results with duplicated `idFoo`'s like so:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | idFoo | serialNumber |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 2     | 56454        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 2  | 3     | 75757        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 3  | 3     | 00909        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 4  | 1     | 64421        |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

What I need is this:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | idFoo | serialNumber |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 2     | 56454        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 3  | 3     | 00909        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 4  | 1     | 64421        |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

I can take the result and use Javascript to filter out the duplicates. I'd specifically like to avoid that and write this in Knex.

The question is how can I do this with Knex code?

I know it can be done with plain SQL (perhaps something using `GROUP BY`) but I'd specifically like to achieve this in "pure" knex without using raw SQL.

Comment: well dont know knex, but looks like you could `group by` to remove duplicates. can show what is your current result and what result you expect?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza edited :)

Comment: is weird, why result is `{2, 3, 00909}` you merge two rows? Those rows with `idFoo = 3` arent duplicates, you need expand on what is your `remove duplicates` logic

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Not merging rows, it's a typo when I was creating the tables in text format to add in the question (fixing now) - remove duplicates based on `idFoo` - no 2 rows should have the same `idFoo`

Comment: But why you keep `{3, 3, 00909}` and discard `{2, 3, 75757}` what is the logic? Choose random? the smallest `serialNumber`  the biggest `id` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza gotcha, I'd like to keep the one with the highest `id` if there's duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal sql you do it like this.

You perform a `self join` and try to find a row with same `idFoo` but bigger `id`, if you dont find it you have `NULL`. And will know you are the bigger one.

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.idFoo, t1.serialNumber
 FROM foo as t1
 LEFT JOIN foo as t2
   ON t1.id < t2.id
  AND t1.idFoo = t2.idFoo  
 WHERE t2.idFoo IS NULL
```

So check for `left join` on knex.js

**EDIT:**

Just check documentation build this (not tested):

```
 knex.select('t1.*')
     .from('foo as t1')
     .leftJoin('foo as t2', function() {
        this.on('t1.id', '<', 't2.id')
            .andOn('t1.idFoo ', '=', 't2.idFoo')
        })
     .whereNull("t2.idFoo")
```

Comment: Apologies - Adding your last `WHERE IS NULL` clause fixes it

Comment: Ups .... forgot that ... but hey I did it for just reading the manual :P. Feel free to edit with the final query.

Comment: Nailed it - Tbh I didn't use the exact code structure you posted (yours translates to nested `JOIN`'s if I'm not mistaken) - the example above it is the one I've used - I'm also reading on how to eat an elephant, ty for the article :P

Comment: Well thanks for the points, but you can also answer your own question with the final result, so other can use the knowledge.

Comment: I think you should probably edit your answer to include my knex code and I'll re accept yours (and delete mine) - doesn't make sense to accept my answer which is a slight tweak of yours

Comment: well in this case are almost the same. In those cases you could just edit my answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it is working...but can ypu pelase xplain the syntax ? Why you use < on the first on ?

Answer (score 3):

Knex.js supports [groupBy](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-groupBy) natively. You can write:

```
knex('foo').whereIn('id',
  knex('foo').max('id').groupBy('idFoo')
)
```

Which is rewritten to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT max(id) FROM foo
      GROUP BY idFoo
  )
```

Note that you need to use the subselect to make sure you won't mix values from diffrent rows within the same group.